# How to loop through linked nodes that have two nodes

Tags: c++, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I want to loop through this node system making sure to hit each node, and I don't want to use recursion. Each node actually has two linked nodes. I don't know if this is called a double linked list or something.

A node looks like

```
class Node {
    private:
       Node* next_node_type_a;
       Node* next_node_type_b;
}
```

Diagram

```
                                         |next_node_type_a| -> 
                 |next_node_type_a|  ->  |next_node_type_b| ->
|start-node|  ->  
                 |next_node_type_b|  ->  |next_node_type_a| ->
                                         |next_node_type_b| ->
```

Originally I didn't see the second node, so I had

```
while(node){
    DoStuffWithNode(node);
    node = node->GetNextNodeTypeA();
}
```

But how can I modify this to traverse both node paths still using a while loop?

Here's some example code that could be worked on

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Node {
 public:
    Node* node_left;
    Node* node_right;
    std::string value;
    Node();
};
Node::Node(){
    node_left = 0;
    node_right = 0;
}

int main()
{
    Node start;
    Node a;
    Node b;
    Node c;
    Node d;
    Node e;
    Node f;

    start.value = "start";
    a.value = "a";
    b.value = "b";
    c.value = "c";
    d.value = "d";
    e.value = "e";
    f.value = "f";

    start.node_left = &a;
    start.node_right = &b;
    a.node_left = &c;
    a.node_right = &d;
    b.node_left = &e;
    b.node_right = &f;

    Node *n = &start;
    while(n){
      std::cout << "New node: " << n->value << std::endl;
      n = n->node_left;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Edit: I just realized this is a tree.

Comment: That's called a binary tree. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417358/function-to-traverse-a-binary-tree) question for some pointers

Comment: "and I don't want to use recursion." -Would be beneficial to cite a reason, as it is the idiomatic approach to traversing a tree.

Comment: @Rotem Doesn't an iterative implementation always trump a recursive? No worries of blowing the stack

Comment: @errno_44 Not sure I agree with that, but I've posted an iterative answer regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion is the idiomatic way of iterating over a binary tree as demonstrated in the other answers, **but** if you require an iterative solution, you can use an additional data structure such as a [`std::queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/) to iteratively traverse all the nodes.

This is known as [Breadth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and it's important to note that the order of traversal will be different than that of recursion, which is an implementation of [Depth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

```
std::queue<Node*> nodesToVisit;
nodesToVisit.push(&start);

while (nodesToVisit.size()) 
{
    Node* n = nodesToVisit.front();
    nodesToVisit.pop();
    std::cout << "New node: " << n->value << std::endl;
    if (n->node_left)
    {
        nodesToVisit.push(n->node_left);
    }
    if (n->node_right)
    {
        nodesToVisit.push(n->node_right);
    }
}
```

The same approach will also work for non-binary trees, but requires additional code for handling cyclical graphs, such as keeping track of all visited nodes in a `std::set`.

Comment: +1 for an actual answer considering the 'non recursive' aspect. Also BFS will not only work on trees but on undirected graphs too.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to use recursivity. Since the depth of a (balanced) binary tree is `O(ln(n))` you can safely assume you wont get a stack overflow.

```
void apply(Node* n)
{
    if (n == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    DoStuffWithNode(n);
    apply(n->node_left);
    apply(n->node_right);
}
```

Comment: the method is called `apply` but it calls out to `DoStuffWithNode` and does not recurse to `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

Recursively visiting each node could do it: the following will result in a depth first search

```
std::vector<Node*> BuildList(Node* root) {
    vector<Node*> nodes;

    if(root) {
        nodes.push_back(root);
        BuildList(root, nodes);
    }

    return nodes;
}

void BuildList(Node* node, std::vector<Node*> current) {
    if(node->next_node_type_a) {
        current.push_back(node->next_node_type_a);
        BuildList(node->next_node_type_a, current);
    }

    if(node->next_node_type_b) {
        current.push_back(node->next_node_type_b);
        BuildList(node->next_node_type_b, current);
    }
}
```

Of course, this could fail if your nodes link back to themselves, so consider swapping out `std::vector` for a set type

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you are using is a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree). To traverse through your binary tree *without* recursion, use the [breadth-first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) approach, which involves using a [queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/) to hold each node and process it.

Adding a *.discovered* value on the Node class will prevent processing any Node twice. Reset this discovered value after processing all Nodes if you want to reuse this function. Using this value is only necessary if you cannot gaurantee that any Node points to an ancestor Node or points to itself.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <queue> 
using namespace std;

void BreadthFirst(Node start) {
    Queue<Node> Q;
    start.discovered = true;
    Q.push(start)
    while (!Q.isEmpty()) {
        Node n = Q.pop()
        cout << n.value << endl;
        if (n->next_node_type_a != null) {
            if(n->next_node_type_a.discovered == false) {
                n->next_node_type_a.discovered = true;
                Q.push(n->next_node_type_a);
            }
        }
        if (n->next_node_type_b != null) {
            if(n->next_node_type_b.discovered == false) {
                n->next_node_type_b.discovered = true;
                Q.push(n->next_node_type_b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the reasoning for having `discovered` as a property on the nodes? How do you reset them all to `false` after traversing the tree, without traversing the tree? I think it would make more sense to use a `std::set` for the purpose of handling cyclical graphs. It would also keep the solution more generic.

Comment: The `discovered` value is only necessary if it cannot be discerned for certain that any Node points to an ancestor or itself. A quick way to reset would be to implement a inherited class of the Node class (ex. `QNode`) that has a public boolean `discovered`. Then, use this class in place of the `Node` class inside the BreadthFirst method.
Finding the correct implementation for OP's question would need more detail as to whether his tree has cycles or if memory is an issue.